# Customize and Rebrand JasperReports Server 5.0

Tags: jasperserver

I want to customize the look and feel of *JasperReports Server*.

I am using *JR Server 5.0*.

I would want to change the logo, title and color of the jasperserver.
I tried searching for documentation on how to achieve the same. But could not find anything for 5.0

I found one documentation for *JR Server 2.0*
http://www.jaspersoft.com/download/customizing-and-rebranding-jaspersoft-user-interface

I initially thought the modifications would be on similar lines but it isn't the case.
For change in the title, it is as per the documentation,
But to change the logo the mentioned files and the edits are not in sync.

What are the modifications needed to be done to achieve the same in 5.0? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an override.CSS which help to introduce customize theme to jasper .This should solve ur problem